# ERROR 1067 (42000) Invalid default value '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql, sql

Importing an SQL file via SSH on Ubuntu server using SQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

The line that the error points to is this line:

```
 CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
```

The line that has user_registered is this line:

```
   `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Not sure what is wrong.

The whole CREATE TABLE command as requested:

```
 CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
`ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ;
```

Comment: can you show the full `CREATE TABLE` command?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch post updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using MySQL 5.7 (or higher). There the default value for [SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) is among others `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE`.

You can check this with

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
/* or...*/
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

Either you remove above mentioned values from the sql mode, or you just make your column nullable and store `NULL` instead of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. I'd prefer the latter. It doesn't waste storage and is clear in its meaning.

Comment: So it would be like this? `user_registered` datetime NULL DEFAULT ' ',

Comment: Rather `user_registered datetime NULL DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: There were more errors in the SQL file but they had the same error with the zero in the date.  Fixed them all with your solution.